# Docker - Fail to run container from imported image with entrypoint

Tags: docker

I have an official MySQL container. I do

```
docker export <cont_name> > ~/Desktop/mysql.tar
```

Next I do

```
sudo tar -c ~/Desktop/mysql.tar | docker import --change "ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" --change "ENV MYSQL_MAJOR 5.7" --change "ENV MYSQL_VERSION 5.7.8-rc" --change "ENTRYPOINT [\"/entrypoint.sh\"]" --change "EXPOSE 3306" --change "VOLUME /var/lib/mysql" --change "CMD [\"mysqld\"]" - mysql:kyriakos
```

and finally

```
docker run --env "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root" --name mysql_kyr mysql:kyriakos
```

and I get

```
exec: "/entrypoint.sh": stat /entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container a15613493ee94a159ff0821974742350ae5df26b0f659932dc7cb3264295e944: [8] System error: exec: "/entrypoint.sh": stat /entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory
```

Am I doing something wrong with the import? In the .tar file the `/entrypoint.sh` seems to exist..

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What exactly do you think this is doing?

```
sudo tar -c ~/Desktop/mysql.tar | docker import
```

- you don't need `sudo`, because you just created this file in your home directory.
- This is *already* a tar file.  By using `tar -c` you are creating a *new* tar archive, the contents of which is `mysql.tar`.  You are passing this to `docker import`.
- This gives you an image that contains a single file, `mysql.tar`, so of course you get the error regarding `/entrypoint.sh` not existing.

I think what you really want is:

```
docker import --change "ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin" \
  --change "ENV MYSQL_MAJOR 5.7" \
  --change "ENV MYSQL_VERSION 5.7.8-rc" \
  --change "ENTRYPOINT [\"/entrypoint.sh\"]" \
  --change "EXPOSE 3306" \
  --change "VOLUME /var/lib/mysql" \
  --change "CMD [\"mysqld\"]" - mysql:kyriakos < mysql.tar
```

And what you  **really** want is to use a Dockerfile, rather than this weird export/import pipeline.

```
FROM mysql

ENV MYSQL_MAJOR 5.7
ENV MYSQL_VERSION 5.7.8
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3306
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql
CMD ["mysqld"]
```