# how to remove all the build history of a docker image?

Tags: docker

When you do `docker history <image_name>`, it will display the full history of the docker image build. Is there a way to remove this history?

I've tried `docker build --squash ...` but it did not work. The history persists.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by removing the history?

Comment: @BMitch  Sensitive information is stored without any protection mechanism to ensure it is not easily disclosed and/or is stored in a clear/readable format. In this case, the docker image history gives enough sensitive data like default user-names and passwords.

Comment: @V-Q-ANGUYEN a username would often be visible within the image outside of the history. For passwords, I wouldn't want those in the image at all, that belongs as configuration of the container. Or for pulling from private repos, move that outside of the Dockerfile and into the CI system. I try to treat the Dockerfile as public knowledge, and that includes the history it generates, makes it a lot easier to secure when there's nothing to secure and the image is just libraries, binaries, and scripts.

Comment: @BMitch: there're a lot of people didn't do that. They used COPY or ADD with sensitive information (passwords, private keys, and API tokens) in a Dockerfile and try to remove all the build history of docker image.

Comment: @V-Q-ANGUYEN bad news for them, removing the history, which is an optional field in the image config.json, doesn't remove the filesystem layer. Trying to help them with a command to purge the image history wouldn't be useful unless that command also purged the layers themselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a multistage build. This is an example for a tomcat image:

```
docker pull tomcat:7-jre8
docker history tomcat:7-jre8
```

This shows you the full history of the image.

I now create a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre8 as orig

FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=orig / /
```

I build it:

```
docker build -t mytomcat:1.0 .
```

If I check the history this is what I see now:

```
docker history mytomcat:1.0

IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
c3cde992658a        6 minutes ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f31f2e5f414562467…   454MB
5cb3aa00f899        6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B
<missing>           6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:88875982b0512a9d0…   5.53MB
```

Test the new image:

```
docker run -ti --rm mytomcat:1.0 bash

root@62d8c9934bd4:/# /usr/local/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
root@62d8c9934bd4:/# curl http://localhost:8080
...
```

Hope this is what you  are looking for. If not let me know.

Comment: That throws an error for me : 
``` => ERROR [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=orig / /                                                                                            8.3s
------
 > [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=orig / /:
------
cannot replace to directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/j1ucwf3y2r43cbugs8e3u4vf9/merged/var/lock with file```

BUT, I believe if I made it work, it would still include the history from alpine:latest, as your example demonstrates. I suppose if you could copy everything from / to / it wipes any previous secrets, so just about achieves what OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Not somewhere I can test this, but does it work to do a `docker export` of the image, and then `docker import`? This “flattens” all images into a container filesystem, removing the history along the way, I believe. [This](https://tuhrig.de/flatten-a-docker-container-or-image/) blog post seems to support the idea.

Comment: yes, just be aware that doing so will make you lose metadata like ENV, ENTRYPOINT and CMD. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026562/docker-fail-to-run-container-from-imported-image-with-entrypoint. You should leverage --change to add those again when importing as export is not exporting them. This is by design and not going to change.

Comment: NB You can only export a container and not an image. You can "docker create <image>" to create a container from <image>.